# Is looping thorugh PCAP twice not possible with io.pkts?

Tags: java, io

I am trying to parse a pcap file two different ways by using two different methods. The pcap file is passed to the class when it is created that contains both methods. When i use the pcap file in the first method no problem looping. However, when i go to parse through it a second time in the second method nothing happens when i try to print each packet. I tried passing the pcap file directly to the second method and still no dice. Do I need to reset a counter/pointer? Any ideas?

How pcap file is loaded from disk

```
pcap = Pcap.openStream(pcapPath);
```

How class constructor intakes pcap file

```
    public PcapParsing(Pcap pcap) {
    this.pcap = pcap;
}
```

How both methods parse the pcap file

```
    public void arpFloodDetect(Pcap ppcap)
{

    try {
        ppcap.loop((final Packet packet) -> {

            System.out.println(ppcap.toString());



            return true;
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to reset a counter/pointer?

You need to create a new `Pcap` by calling `Pcap.openStream` again.   The `Pcap` API does not expose any methods for resetting the underlying stream.

---

> Pcap files can get large like a couple gigs or larger. Will this add a significant load penalty for each time i call it?

It depends on how good your file system is.  If we assume that your file system is on a fast local SSD, and you are running an OS which uses RAM for file system buffer caching, then the reading a big file will be fast the first time, and faster the second time.

It also depends on what you mean by "significant", and what is acceptable.  And how much money you are prepared to pay to upgrade your hardware to achieve acceptable performance.

> Would you happen to know a different way of loading files that avoids a penalty if there is one?

Basically, no.

The only other alternatives I can think of involve read or mapping the entire file into the JVM's address space and then wrapping it in an `InputStream`.  You still need to create a `Pcap` for each pass through the file.

But the problem with this is that it requires as much JVM address space as the size of the file you are processing.  If the file is *significantly* bigger than the amount of physical RAM available, it can get horrible:

- In the best case your performance will be equivalent to re-reading the file from disk.
- In the worst case your application thrashes and brings the operating system to its knees (or gets OOM-killed to prevent that).

The current Pcap implementation is designed to avoid that by *not* caching the data in RAM.  That is how it is able to cope with huge input files without running out of memory, etc.

Comment: Pcap files can get large like a couple gigs or larger. Will this add a significant load penalty for each time i call it? Would you happen to know a different way of loading files that avoids a penalty if there is one?